# is it possible to use FlutterSimpleStickerView with image stored to File variable?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

is there a way to use the package flutter_simple_sticker_view.dart with an image stored to a variable ?

I get this error: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider - The image to be painted into the decoration.
Typically this will be an AssetImage (for an image shipped with the application) or a NetworkImage (for an image obtained from the network).

source: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_simple_sticker_view

my code:

````
...
import 'package:flutter_simple_sticker_view/flutter_simple_sticker_view.dart';

File image;

FlutterSimpleStickerView(
                  Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: Image.file(widget.image))),           //originally NetworkImage(..)
                  [
                    Image.asset("assets/stickers/test1.PNG"),
                    Image.asset("assets/stickers/test2.png"),

                  ],
                ),
        ),```
````